# Grafana with elasticsearch data source

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am currently running the latest (master) of grafana which supports elasticsearch as data source. I am able to connect to elasticsearch but cannot find docs on structure for storing metrics in elasticsearch.

I know it's not officially released yet but since I am already running elasticserach it would be nice not to setup another data source like influxDB.

Does anybody has experience with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok found it, basically you can use whatever structure you want as long as there is and `@timestamp` attribute. Example:

```
{ @timestamp: '2015-10-22T12:00:00.000 +0200', 
  name: 'my event',
  load: 0.5,
  cpu: 50      
}
```

Now you can filter, group or search these attributes in grafana.

Comment: you need a date field but it can be named anything (set timestamp field in data source config or in query editor)